# Get or Check IE compatibility view settings

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am working on a single sign on between an page I control and a page I do not.  Unfortunately, their page needs to be viewed in compatibility view if you are using IE9 or higher.  I have built out a function to check for

```
if(!document.documentMode || document.documentMode < 8)
```

before redirecting, but sadly that will only check if my page is in the compatibility view list, what I need to do is check if *their* page is in the list.  Is this possible in Java, JavaScript, or JSP, and if so, how?  I have looked online and no one makes any mention of checking if another site will be viewed in compatibility view.

Note: The provider of the site I am connecting to refuses to make any adjustments for this purpose.